side by side list relationships network graph javascript
I have two lists of names. One is the boss the other are the employees. I can format the data however is needed.
On the left hand side I will have a list of the boss names, and on the right I will have a list of the employee names. It is a one-to-many cardinality, where one boss can have many employees.
I just want a thin line joining the names left and right. So one boss will have lines coming in from multiple employess. Ideally it's responsive.
I tried D3.js a bunch of other visualization suites but they all seem overkill, for such a simple graph.
